# click() event doesn't need full class name?

Tags: jquery

I have these input objects as follows,

```
 <input type='radio' class="but option" value='Yesterday'>
<input type='radio' class="but option" value='Last Week'>  
<input type='radio' class="but option" value='Last Month'>
<input type='radio' class="but option" value='All Time'>
```

and I have a jquery click event handler that says `$(".but").click(function() {`

These input objects are getting caught in this event handler and I'm wondering why when their class names are not "but"

Comment: change your class name to `but_option` if it is only meant to be a single class, or my preferred way would be `butOption`

Comment: But their classname IS `but`, and `option`, they have two classes

Comment: yes but its not what they want I dont think.  I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have spaces in a `class` attribute then you're assigning *multiple* classes, not one with a space in its name. So your inputs have two classes: "but" and "option".

When you're matching on class names (e.g. with jQuery) then it will match any element that has that class, even if the element has other classes as well. That's why all your inputs (that all have a class "but" as well as another class) are matched.

You can read more about this for example in the relevant [html4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) and [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes) documents at W3, or over at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes).